# google maps on my website compatible with mobile?

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

i need to implement a google maps in my bootstrap but im not sure if an iframe will work for mobiles, is there a version of google maps for both mobile and desktop

i tried google but nothing comes up

```
<iframe id="maps" width="325" height="208" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
                src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=8207+Central+Ave+NE,+Albuquerque,+NM&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=8207+central+ave+ne+a&amp;sll=34.166233,-106.026069&amp;sspn=15.047206,19.753418&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=8207+Central+Ave+NE,+Albuquerque,+Bernalillo,+New+Mexico+87108&amp;ll=35.074854,-106.555821&amp;spn=0.00364,0.004823&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=8207+Central+Ave+NE,+Albuquerque,+NM&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=8207+central+ave+ne+a&amp;sll=34.166233,-106.026069&amp;sspn=15.047206,19.753418&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=8207+Central+Ave+NE,+Albuquerque,+Bernalillo,+New+Mexico+87108&amp;ll=35.074854,-106.555821&amp;spn=0.00364,0.004823&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" style=" color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) was developed for both mobile and desktop devices. Just make sure you set the **viewport** meta-tag, and style the **html**, **body** and **map div** (id **map-canvas** below) to be:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
```

Study the [Hello world](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) example to see how to get it all working.